# setTimeout() for method that is undefined at runtime?

Tags: javascript, undefined, settimeout

When calling a method within `setTimeout()`, must the method be defined at run-time, when the timeout is set? Or will `setTimeout()` also work with variables and methods that are loaded in later, after the initial run-time?

Context: I am using an external module. I wish to use a method from that module within a `setTimeout()` call.

I believe that this would not work. However, I am unable to produce a failure case. I expected to receive a `TypeError: ${method} is undefined`, but I have not yet.

--

Edit: To be explicit:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  someMethod()
})

// where someMethod loads 1-3 seconds after page load
```

Comment: Typo? Your question is asking "Does it have to be defined at run-time, or can it be defined at run-time?"

Comment: depends on how you write the code. So how did you write the code.

Comment: Passing a reference to setTimeout that is undefined won't work, but calling something initially undefined inside the function passed to it works fine, as long as it's a function when the timeout expires. `setTimeout(() => f(), 100);` works fine if `f` points to a function inside the next 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Side note : importing at top is not done at run time. Only dynamic imports are actually run time

Comment: Got it, thank you @ChrisG. Do you have a source for that? I couldn't find anything relevant on MDN. Thanks again

Comment: I just tested in on jsfiddle. There's no MDN docs for this because function code runs when the function is called, so this is in no way a special or edge case. JS behaves exactly as expected.

Comment: That phrasing - the function runs when it is called - made this click for me. Seems obvious but that wording helped. Obviously, within a timeout, code isn't executed until the timeout lapses. Thus, if your method becomes defined before then, it will be available after the timeout. Thanks again @ChrisG